# sort javascript array by object attribute

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort my array by lastName attribute. The array stays exactly the same. Here is the code:

```
console.log(clientListArray);
    //sort clientList by last name
    var sortedtClientListArray = clientListArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        console.log(obj1.lastName);
        return obj1.lastName - obj2.lastName;
    })
    console.log(sortedtClientListArray);
```

A console.log of my array that stays the same (diving in to the 4th element (index 3)):

```
0: ct.extend.init
1: ct.extend.init
2: ct.extend.init
3: ct.extend.init
_events: Object
dwelling: "RH07"
firstName: "Alan"
lastName: "Mosby"
letter: "M"
nhi: ""
oid: "2143.10"
parent: function (){return i}
uid: "79fbbf40-5545-4cdc-bc2b-088bf56affc6"
__proto__: r
4: ct.extend.init
5: ct.extend.init
6: ct.extend.init
7: ct.extend.init
length: 8
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Why is the order of objects in the array not changing?

The full method that it is inside:

```
function onClientClick(e) {


    console.log(e.dataItem);
    var clientList = e.sender.dataSource._data;
    console.log(clientList);
    var clientListArray = [];
    for(i=0; i < clientList.length; i++){
        clientListArray.push(clientList[i]);
    }
    console.log(clientListArray);
    //sort clientList by last name
    var sortedtClientListArray = clientListArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
        console.log(obj1.lastName);
        return obj1.lastName - obj2.lastName;
    })
    console.log(sortedtClientListArray);

    for(i=0; i < clientList.length; i++){
        var clientID = clientList[i].oid;
        if(clientID == e.dataItem.oid) {
            theClient = new Client(clientList[i]);
            console.log(i);
            console.log(theClient.name);
            navigateToSingleClient(true, clientList[i], true, clientList, i);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: can you post the content of array.

Comment: @Mritunjay Have I not done that? The console.log of the array?

Comment: Nope, we can only see the attributes of one item.

Comment: got the problem added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

**1)** `"OneString"-"SecondString"` will return `NaN`. So ca return that in this situation.

**2)** `Array.sort` sorts the given array in place. It returns the sorted array.

Say like this

```
clientListArray.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.lastName < b.lastName) return -1;
    if(a.lastName > b.lastName) return 1;
    return 0;
})
```

Comment: According to MDN "The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array." so it does return the array.

Comment: But you say "it doesn't return an array." but MDN says it does return an array.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey My Bad, Updated the answer. Though I am not sure why would you sort the array in place and then return the sorted array back.